# Sort by name and number

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an Array

```
people = [
        { "name": "Bob Mike", "nickname": "john" , "points": 5 ) },
        { "name": "Andrea Maria", "nickname": "bob", "points": 5 )}
        { "name": "Larry Kiu", "nickname": "larry", "points": 4 ) }
    ];
```

I want to sort it like this

```
Andrea Maria - 5
Bob Mike - 5
Larry Kiu - 4
```

I'm not into the Sort Method, I found this little Code, but it only Sorts the Points, not including the ASC from the name field.

```
people.sort(dynamicSort('name')).sort(dynamicSort('points'));

function dynamicSort(property) {return function(a, b) {
   return (a[property] > b[property]) ? -1 : (a[property] < b[property])? 1 : 0;
}}
```

**Edit: Thank you Erazihel**

Comment: Not the DV but... "I'm not into the Sort Method": so...? We don't use things because we like/dislike them, we use them because they're the best/only tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `localeCompare` to compare two strings

```js
const people = [
 { name: "Bob Mike", nickname: "john" , points: 5 },
 { name: "Andrea Maria", nickname: "bob", points: 5 },
 { name: "Larry Kiu", nickname: "larry", points: 4 }
];

people.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.points - a.points || a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
});

console.log(people.map(a => a.name + ' - ' + a.points));
```

Comment: Thank you. This Works Perfect. Have a nice Weekend ^^!

Answer (score 3):

You can first sort by points and then use `localeCompare` to sort by names.

```js
var people = [
 { "name": "Bob Mike", "nickname": "john" , "points": 5 },
 { "name": "Andrea Maria", "nickname": "bob", "points": 5},
 { "name": "Larry Kiu", "nickname": "larry", "points": 4 }
];

people.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.points - a.points || a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
})

console.log(people)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like this

```js
var people = [
 { "name": "Bob Mike", "nickname": "john" , "points": 5 },
 { "name": "Andrea Maria", "nickname": "bob", "points": 5},
 { "name": "Larry Kiu", "nickname": "larry", "points": 4 }
];

people.sort(compare('name')).sort(compare('points'));

function compare(property){
 return function(a, b){
  return a[property] <= b[property];
 }
}


console.log(people);
```

the compare function returns a function which would work on the property specified

Answer (score 0):

By keeping the idea of a function for checking a single key of the object for sorting, you could use an array with the keys for sorting with their order and build a new array with the callbacks for using with sort.

In the sort callbak, the functions are invoked until the result value is different from a truthy value, which stops the iteration.

```js
function dynamicSort(key, order) {
    return function(a, b) {
        return +(order === 'ASC' || -1) * +(a[key] < b[key] && -1 || a[key] > b[key]);
    };
}

var people = [{ name: "Bob Mike", nickname: "john" , points: 5 }, { name: "Andrea Maria", nickname: "bob", points: 5 }, { name: "Larry Kiu", nickname: "larry", points: 4 }],
    sortBy = [['points', 'DESC'], ['name', 'ASC']].map(a => dynamicSort(...a));

people.sort(function (a, b) {
    var v = 0;
    sortBy.some(f => v = v || f(a, b));
    return v;
});

console.log(people);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```